# repeating a string n times, when n is specified in vector

Tags: r

I'm a beginner at R and have what I believe to be a fairly easy task, but somehow I can't seem to find a good solution.

I'm trying ot write a for loop that repeats a string of natural numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, ...) for the length of the number in `vector`, and repeats this procedure until its moved through `vector`. 
This was what i first thought would do it:

```
vector <- c(5, 3, 1, 3, 2)
for(i in vector) {
seq <- rep_len(1:10, length.out = vector[i])
}
```

But this is the output:

```
seq
[1] 1 2 3
```

Instead, I want the following output:

```
seq
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 1 2 3 1 2
```

How do I index the vector correctly?

Comment: `sequence(vector)`

Comment: I think this from the `?sequence` help page: "it mainly exists in reverence to the very early history of R." How thoughtful.

Comment: If you don't like `sequence` you could use `unlist(sapply(vector, function(i) 1:i))`

Comment: You should note that the `for` loop of your own solution is flawed, because you're rewriting `seq` with every step.

Comment: you can also `Vectorize` `rep_len`: `unlist(Vectorize(rep_len, 'length.out')(1:10, vector))`